# Japanese font error when previewing PDF with react-pdf-viewer React JS

Tags: reactjs, pdf, preview

When I preview a pdf document in Japanese, I get an error like this: ==================================================================== Warning: Setting up fake worker. util.js:425 Warning: loadFont - translateFont failed: "UnknownErrorException: CMapReaderFactory not initialized, see the useWorkerFetch parameter.". util.js:425 Warning: Error during font loading: CMapReaderFactory not initialized, see the useWorkerFetch parameter. util.js:425 Warning: loadFont - translateFont failed: "UnknownErrorException: CMapReaderFactory not initialized, see the useWorkerFetch parameter.". util.js:425 Warning: Error during font loading: CMapReaderFactory not initialized, see the useWorkerFetch parameter. util.js:425 Warning: loadFont - translateFont failed: "UnknownErrorException: CMapReaderFactory not initialized, see the useWorkerFetch parameter.". util.js:425 Warning: Error during font loading: CMapReaderFactory not initialized, see the useWorkerFetch parameter. util.js:425 Warning: loadFont - translateFont failed: "UnknownErrorException: CMapReaderFactory not initialized, see the useWorkerFetch parameter.". util.js:425 Warning: Error during font loading: CMapReaderFactory not initialized, see the useWorkerFetch parameter. util.js:425 Warning: loadFont - translateFont failed: "UnknownErrorException: CMapReaderFactory not initialized, see the useWorkerFetch parameter.". util.js:425 Warning: Error during font loading: CMapReaderFactory not initialized, see the useWorkerFetch parameter. util.js:425 Warning: loadFont - translateFont failed: "UnknownErrorException: CMapReaderFactory not initialized, see the useWorkerFetch parameter.". util.js:425 Warning: Error during font loading: CMapReaderFactory not initialized, see the useWorkerFetch parameter. util.js:425 Warning: loadFont - translateFont failed: "UnknownErrorException: CMapReaderFactory not initialized, see the useWorkerFetch parameter.". util.js:425 Warning: Error during font loading: CMapReaderFactory not initialized, see the useWorkerFetch parameter. I still don't know how to handle it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.